# VisualWebpart - controls like radiobuttonlist and dropdownlist not firing the SelectedIndexChanged event when inside a repeater datarow

Tags: visual-web-part, dropdown

VisualWebpart - controls like radiobuttonlist and dropdownlist not firing the SelectedIndexChanged event when inside a repeater datarow.

Any help?

Source code:

Site URL
        
                             
    
    
        
            HyperLink
        
    
    
        
             
        
             
    
    
        
            Admins
        
             
    
    
        
            
            
        
        
             
    
    
        

        
        
            
                1
                2
            
        
    
    
        
            
            **The following are identified as the child sites of the above site, please select the appropriate properties next to it.**
                
                
                
                
                   
                    Inherit Parent Site
                    Do-not Inherit Parent Site
                
                
                Select
                EMEA
                LTAM
            
                
                
                
                 
                
                
                
               
                --%>

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace DeriveMigrationData.DeriveSiteAdminForm
{
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    public partial class DeriveSiteAdminForm : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

```
    DataTable dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string siteurl; string admins;

        int itemid = SPContext.Current.ItemId;

        dt = BLL.SiteAdminData.GetAdminsData(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, SPContext.Current.ListId);
        BLL.SiteAdminData.GetCurrentItem(dt, itemid, out siteurl, out admins);
        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = siteurl;
        HyperLink1.Text = siteurl;
        string[] adm = admins.Split(';');
        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = BLL.SiteAdminData.getResolvedUsers(adm, SPContext.Current.Web);
        //RadioButtonList1.DataSource = adm;
        RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "LoginName";
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
        BindChildSites(dt, siteurl);

    }

    private void BindChildSites(DataTable dt, string siteurl)
    {

        RpChildSites.DataSource = BLL.SiteAdminData.GetAdminsSiteChilds(dt, siteurl);
        RpChildSites.DataBind();

        //GridView1.DataSource = RpChildSites.DataSource;
        //GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void RBinheritParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButtonList)sender).SelectedValue.Equals("Inherit"))
        {
            //showthe current row prop
        }

    }

    protected void RpChildSites_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       ControlCollection c = (ControlCollection)RpChildSites.Controls;
    }

    protected void DDRegion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //triggers on the region change, load other data
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //test
    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Both of the controls you mention have the autopostback property set to false as default. I can not see that you set autopostback to true in your code. So if you are not doing that in your markup either, be sure to set that property and your selectindexchanged should be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to handle the event "ItemDataBound" of the repeater. In the EventHandler you can get the control with e.Item.FindControl("ControlID") and then attache your event here.